# Qt dll class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, qt5, dllimport

I've built a simple dynamic library (dll) with Qt5.9. Now, I need to integrate the dll functionalities in one tool developed by a colleague of mine, developed in Visual Studio C#. And here starts my problem.

I know that Qt (C++) library class could not be directly used in C#, since it's unmanaged code. But, if use DllImport I just only "wrap" single methods of the class itself, since the dll is exposed as a C interface, not a C++ (if I understand well googling on the web).

So, after other time spent looking for an answer on the web, I've tried creating a CLR lirary class project in Visual Studio, to build up a C# wrapper of unmanaged class. The problem is that, even if I add all includes and library dependacies (and their paths), I'm unable to build this project, getting linker error "LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x318    C:\Qt5.9\5.9.1\msvc2013_64\bin\Qt5Core.dll" (I've add Qt5Core.dll which is the only one used in my unmanaged class and it seems really strange that dll is corrupted).

So, does anyone have a suggestion to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a linker error, make sure you include the *full text* of the error message.

Comment: You can follow QtSharp's approach, https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp Via CppSharp you might get a good enough binding for your library.

Comment: QtSharp is not the way we'd like to follow

Comment: Did you eventually figure out how to fix this?

Comment: @tunafish24 unfortunately no, just aborted that way.